# Is there a term for the instance when soldiers collide in a battle?

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word which describes that very instant when opposing soldiers, running into each other, collide.

I mean in hand-to-hand combat, like in the medieval times, probably with swords or other such weapons. I am trying to describe the effect/noise/impact the collision would create the first time they collide.

Is there a phrase or a term or a word for that?

Comment: Do you mean as in ***hand-to-hand combat**?* Soldiers don't usually "collide / bump into" enemy soldiers, even in the heat of battle. They use *weapons*. But in the broader sense, a military detachment might ***engage*** the enemy.

Comment: Yes I mean a hand-to-hand combat, like in the medieval times, probably with swords or other such weapons.

Comment: What about "pitched battle"? I think it seems to be the world you are looking for.

Comment: I'm actually trying to describe the effect/noise/impact the collision would create the first time they collide.

Comment: Attack head-on....?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with **collide**, as in your question? I can't think of it normally having a meaning *other* than the instant of contact…

Comment: That's called *melee* or *clash*.

Comment: You could say *plunged into the fray*.

Answer (score 2):

A **clash** is onomatopoeic and given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/clash) as

> **clash**
>   NOUN
>   **3** A loud jarring sound, as of metal objects being struck together.
>
> *Without another thought, they spurred their horses forward as shouts erupted in the air and there was the clash of metal against metal.*

---

And as a verb, Lexico has

> **clash**
>   VERB
>   **1** Meet and come into violent conflict.
>
> *Violence erupted on Tuesday when militants clashed with a bandit gang and 15 people were killed.*